# How to set technical debt for rules which SQALE remediation function is linear?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to set the technical debt issues against rules which SQALE remediation function is linear. I replaced https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-css/blame/master/css-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/css/checks/ImportNumberThreshold.java#L71 by

```
CheckMessage checkMessage = new CheckMessage(this,
    "Reduce the number of @import. This sheet imports {0,number,integer} other sheets, "
      + "{1,number,integer} more than the {2,number,integer} maximum.", currentImportCount,
    currentImportCount - DEFAULT_THRESHOLD, DEFAULT_THRESHOLD);
  checkMessage.setCost(1000.0);
  getContext().log(checkMessage);
```

but it does not set the technical debt to 1,000 minutes. The technical debt remains 10 minutes for each issue whatever the number of imports beyond the limit.

In my test file though, the following assertion is green:

```
   CheckMessagesVerifier.verify(file.getCheckMessages()).next()
  .withMessage("Reduce the number of @import. This sheet imports 32 other sheets, 1 more than the 31 maximum.")
  .withCost(Double.valueOf(1000.0))
  .noMore();
```

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the EffortToFix value. Check this code for an example : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/MethodComplexityCheck.java

Comment: It's what I did, see https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css/blob/Set_cost_linear_function/css-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/css/checks/ImportNumberThreshold.java#L77. The related unit test passes, see https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css/blob/Set_cost_linear_function/css-checks/src/test/java/org/sonar/css/checks/ImportNumberThresholdTest.java#L38. But I always get 40 minutes on the web interface... Not 10 minutes x 4 + 30 minutes = 70 minutes